# Changing the url of an Ajax request dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have an ordinary Datatables in my web page, it looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#mydb').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,             
        "ajax": "/myapi/?item=free&format=datatables",
        "columns": [

            {data: "item",
            {data: "Price"},

        ]
    });
    setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
}, 10000 );
});
```

This table refreshes every 10 seconds, retrieving the latest values from my database.

Now, i would like to add a button to change dynamically the content of the webpage, so that it retrieves the values from `?item=taken` instead of `?item=free`, without refreshing the page.

Here is what i tried:

```
var myvar = 'item=free'

function ChangeVar(){
        myvar = 'item=taken'

    }

$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#mydb').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,             
        "ajax": "/myapi/?'+ myvar + '&format=datatables",
        "columns": [

            {data: "item",
            {data: "Price"},

        ]
    });
    setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
}, 10000 );
});
```

**Html**

```
<button onclick="ChangeVar()" name="button5" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">See taken items</button>
```

I added a button that points to the function `ChangeVar()`, the function should change the main variable's name, which is used in the ajax request. That didn't work, maybe because i'm not using the variable's scope properly, and i think that it wouldn't work because Ajax is asinchronous, so i would need to add something more.

Can someone point me to a solution that would work to this problem?

Comment: Can you using SESSION or LOCAL storages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataTables has its own method to change ajax URL dynamically: `table.ajax.url('URL')`. So you don't have to destroy the object and recreate every time.

I have made the example below so the interval reloads for every interval. However, when using `table.ajax.url('')` you can chain [.load()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url().load()) method to retrieve the data immediately.

See this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let test = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      dataSrc: ''
    },
    columns: [{
        data: 'userId'
      },
      {
        data: 'id'
      },
      {
        data: 'title'
      }
    ]

  });


  changeVar = function() {
    test.ajax.url("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums");
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    test.ajax.reload();
    console.log("Interval");
  }, 10000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <button onclick="changeVar()" name="button5" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">See taken items</button>
  <br><br>
  <div id="container">
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Body</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I didn't know about that method. This is wonderful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are one issue with your code

```
"ajax": "/myapi/?item=free&format=datatables",
```

When you define an ajax URL, the url will be save on the table instance, so modify variable **myvar** will not able to change the url inside table instance.
But Datatable allow you to change the ajax url though API **table.ajax.url(newURL)**.
I also modify the scope of your variable and function, this script bellow will work

```
var myvar = 'item=free';
var table;
function ChangeVar(){
    myvar = 'item=taken'
    table.ajax.url("/myapi/?'+ myvar + '&format=datatables");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    table = $('#mydb').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,             
        "ajax": "/myapi/?'+ myvar + '&format=datatables",
        "columns": [
            {data: "item",
            {data: "Price"},

        ]
    });
    setInterval( function () {
        table.ajax.reload();
    }, 10000 );
});
```

***Do not destroy table and recreate new one, that's not good for performance***

Comment: Yes! ajax.reload was the way to go. I've been suggested to do the same in the other answer, thanks to both of you guys!

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in this code, you are using single quote instead of double quote

```
"ajax": "/myapi/?'+ myvar + '&format=datatables"
```

so js takes myvar as a string and not as a variable.
try

```
 "ajax": "/myapi/?"+ myvar + "&format=datatables"
```

also you missed a closing bracket here  `{data: "item"`

```
var table = $('#mydb').DataTable({
    "serverSide": true,             
    "ajax": "/myapi/?"+ myvar + "&format=datatables",
    "columns": [

        {data: "item"},
        {data: "Price"},

    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
function refreshDataTable(itemName) {
    var table = $('#mydb').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/myapi/?'+ myvar + '&format=datatables",
        "columns": [
            {data: "item"},
            {data: "Price"},
        ]
    });
    setInterval(function () {
        table.ajax.reload();
    }, 10000);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    refreshDataTable('item=free');
    $('#change-item-btn').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        refreshDataTable('item=taken');
    });
});
```

And in HTML

```
<button id="change-item-btn" name="button5" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">See taken items</button>
```

Good luck, keep coding.

Answer (score 0):

You have to destroy and reinitialise the Datatable each time.

```
var table = null;

function ChangeVar() {
  table.destroy();
  table = $("#mydb").DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "/myapi/?item=taken&format=datatables",
    columns: [{ data: "item" }, { data: "Price" }]
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  table = $("#mydb").DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "/myapi/?item=free&format=datatables",
    columns: [{ data: "item" }, { data: "Price" }]
  });
  setInterval(function() {
    table.ajax.reload();
  }, 10000);
});
```

more info:
https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3#destroy

Comment: Please add appropriate tags to question.

Comment: Hey! I tried this, the problem is that when i hit the button, the table is not destroyed!

Comment: Hi @Jack022, so what happened? is there an error or something?

Comment: Tried looking into the console but no error is showing there; i'm now trying to find what's wrong